# Liferay pentaho Integaration throwing error javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Context is read only error

Tags: liferay

Integrating pentaho in liferay using `pentaho.war` and then after starting tomcat getting below error:

```
06:01:23,701 ERROR [JNDIResourceProvider] error closing context
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Context is read only
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.checkWritable(NamingContext.java:962) at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.close(NamingContext.java:762)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.JNDIResourceProvider.close(JNDIResourceProv
ider.java:68)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.CompositeResourceProvider.close(CompositeRe
sourceProvider.java:56)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.initialize(ResourcesFactor
y.java:163)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<init>(ResourcesFactory.ja
va:92)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<clinit>(ResourcesFactory.
java:89)
        at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactoryContextListener.contextInit
ialized(ResourcesFactoryContextListener.java:23)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
t.java:4779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
t.java:5273)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1566)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
java:1556)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat's JNDI implementation is read only.
The error is caused by the SessionFactory trying to remove itself from JNDI.

Its not that serious, all you are getting is an ungraceful shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a file named **resfactory.properties** under *WEB-INF/classes* containing the following line:

**tbeller.usejndi=false**

see: http://jpivot.sourceforge.net/wcf/api/com/tonbeller/tbutils/res/package-summary.html